# Unable to open file alpha.apk You do not have an app installed on this device

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I am trying to build android apk file via `cordova build android`. It gives me an apk at the location of

`D:/wamp/www/templateproject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk`

When I try to open that app in my mobile i get this alert message.

`Unable to open file android-debug.apk. You do not have an app installed on this device to open this type of file.`

Note: I have already check the installation from unknown sources.

How do I open such file ?

[image]

Note: It seems working with my friend device `Redmi note 3` but not working with my device `Redmi note 4` and `moto g2` not sure what is the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the updated skype. I was trying to share the apk file via desktop skype to android skype. With the latest update on skype it was not allowing me to open apk file. Bug with the skype. However the file is working fine if I try to access it from file manager.

The reason Redmi note 3 was working because it had skype of older version and other two mobile like redmi note 4 and moto g2 had updated one.

Comment: Thanks man! This weird problem is nowhere addressed on the internet except yours.. :)

Comment: and if you don't know where is it, FileManager>Internal Storage>Download